# ASP.NET ODBC Query with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, odbc

Please help me, I don't know what can be wrong with the following code:

```
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString);
        String query = "INSERT INTO customer (custId, custName, custPass, "+
                       "custEmail, custAddress, custAge) VALUES (" +
                       "@ID, @Name, @Pass, @Email, @Address, @Age)";

        OdbcCommand exe = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
        exe.Parameters.Add("@ID", OdbcType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = id;
        exe.Parameters.Add("@Name", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = name;
        exe.Parameters.Add("@Pass", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = pass;
        exe.Parameters.Add("@Email", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = email;
        exe.Parameters.Add("@Address", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = address;
        exe.Parameters.Add("@Age", OdbcType.Int).Value = age;
        conn.Open();
        exe.ExecuteNonQuery(); // ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 6.
```

This code throws me `Too few parameters.` error when I am trying to execute query. The database is fine, it works fine when I hardcode values into a query, instead of using parameters.

Thank you.

Comment: try changing pass to passw maybe it is getting mixed up with asp identifier...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From MSDN:

> When CommandType is set to Text, the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC does not support passing named parameters to an SQL statement or to a stored procedure called by an OdbcCommand. In either of these cases, use the question mark (?) placeholder. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
```

Rewrite your query to

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString);
    String query = "INSERT INTO customer (custId, custName, custPass, "+
                   "custEmail, custAddress, custAge) VALUES (" +
                   "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Order of Parameter counts!

EDIT: Parameter can be added this way:

```
OdbcCommand exe = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
exe.Parameters.Add("ID", OdbcType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = id;
exe.Parameters.Add("Name", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = name;
exe.Parameters.Add("Pass", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = pass;
exe.Parameters.Add("Email", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = email;
exe.Parameters.Add("Address", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = address;
exe.Parameters.Add("Age", OdbcType.Int).Value = age;
```

Comment: Using ODBC to FilMaker, this syntax worked perfectly in .NET environment, and YES order of the parameters count!

Comment: If the query parameters aren't named, what purpose does the first parameter in `Parameters.Add()` serve?

Comment: @Scott: Other Data Provider are using named parameter. So I guess the reason is to have same API

Comment: You may still want to use names so you can look up the parameter to set the parameter for subsequent calls.  I haven't tried it in OdbcCommand yet, but they are useful for other database providers.

Answer (score 0):

One of your columns in your query does not exist.
Please check your column names.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll see this when you misspell a column name in your SQL statement.  Are you sure of those column names (custId, custName, etc.)?

Comment: i am pretty sure, since if I change third line of my query to actual values it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try changing pass to passw maybe it is getting mixed up with asp identifier...